Remove extra spacing between subsections in amsart document class
How to remove the extra space between subsections of a given section in amsart document class, so that the distance between two subsections is fixed and equal to the regular distance between two lines?
The problem is, the vertical spacing between subsections on different pages can be quite different (especially when there are equations). There can be ridiculous vertical spacing of 3-4 times the usual value.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}

\subsection{}\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

% how to remove extra space here?

\subsection{}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


Welcome to tex.sx.  While it's possible to do this, the reason for the difference is that, when TeX decides that the page must be ended (whatever is next in the source won't fit on the page), extra space is distributed where stretch is allowed.  So omitting the extra space between subsections will cause greater space to be added elsewhere (or perhaps an "underfull" warning).  An easier approach is to issue \raggedbottom in the preamble, but that may not satisfy you either.

@barbarabeeton I have tried different approaches including \raggedbottom, also \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1}, and bunch of others, and now want to see what happens when the space is completely removed, but could not figure out how to do this.

To remove the stretch before a subsection heading, the definition
for that heading can be patched, as follows:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\subsection
  {.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}
  {1\linespacing}
  {}
  {}{}
\makeatother

I haven't tested this, but have checked the syntax of the patch (by
comparing it to my earlier answer to another question about changing amsart, and based on the
current version of amsart included in TeX Live).  This will remove the
stretch before all subsection headings.  The way amsart is constructed,
it's not known that what came before a new subsection was also a subsection,
and accommodating that would require a significant rewrite of the class file.
If there are no other places on the page that permit stretch, this will
certainly result in a warning message in your log.  If there are math
displays and no section or similar headers on the page, all the stretch
will be divided among the displays, before and after each.  Unlike article and the "standard" LaTeX classes, amsart does not guarantee that the
print area has an integral number of lines adjusted for the metric measure.
So it is likely that there will, if a page includes only text, always be
a slight mismatch.

Thanks. This works after changing 1 in {1\linespacing} to 0. No extra warnings were generated.

I think you're abusing \subsection and I guess you never use \subsection with a title.
However, I'll provide a way to add an optional title in parentheses, that could come in handy.
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@fakesubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@
  \z@ % was .5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing
  {-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\numbered}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \@fakesubsection{}%
  }{%
    \@fakesubsection{(#1)\spacefactor\@M}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}

\numbered
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\numbered[With title]
\lipsum[2]1-3]

\numbered

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}


